# Why am I getting 'an unsupported operand type error?

Tags: python-3.x

I have come across this error while coding, and I have no idea what it means.

```
line 59, in <module>
    filename=class_name + ".csv"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I'm not sure where I messed up, but it might be to do with the validation for the class number.

```
while True:
    try:
        class_name=int(input("Are you in class 1, 2 or 3? "))
        if class_name in [1, 2, 3]:
            print(name,", welcome to this maths test!")
            break 
        else:
            print ("Class has to be 1, 2 or 3")
    except ValueError:
        print ("Class has to be 1, 2 or 3")



filename=class_name + ".csv"

with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(name) + " : " + str(score) + '\n')

if results("Do you wish to view previous results for your class? (yes or no) "):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            print(f.read())
```

Comment: So, you correctly "cast" `class_name` to an `int` on input, so now it's an `int` type. `".csv"` is a s`str` type. You can either `filename = str(class_name) + ".csv"` or `filename = "{}.csv".format(class_name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class_name` is an `int`. You assign it here:

```
class_name=int(input("Are you in class 1, 2 or 3? "))
```

However, you can't concatenate integers and strings, so you have to cast the `int` first to a `str`:

```
filename= str(class_name) + ".csv"
```